# Capybara testing if a fields are seen, but two fields has the same beginning, that cause a problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, capybara

On my Ruby on Rails application, I would like to run a Capybara test. There are two different groups of users: `intern_user` and `extern_user`. There is a form that includes two input fields: `'Comment'` and `'Comment for Interns'`. The `extern_user` should see both of the fields, the `intern_user` should only see `'Comment for Interns'`.

In the case of the `intern_user` I want to test the following feature: `And I do not see the Comment field` and for the in the .rb file I have the following code:

```
 Then(/^I (do not )?see the comment field$/) do |not_visible|
  m = have_field('Comment')

  x = expect(page)
  not_visible ? x.not_to(m) : x.to(m)
end
```

But Capybara is only looking for the beginning of the text, and because there is a field which is called `'Comment for Interns'` the test fails. It is handled as if the user has seen the `'Comment'` field, but actually it does not, it only sees another field, with the same beginning in the name.

How it is possible to set, that Capybara should look for a field, which exactly has the given name and no more characters in it?

Answer (score 1):

By default Capybara does substring matching on locator strings in label contents. To do exact locator matching you should just be able to pass the `:exact` option

```
m = have_field('Comment', exact: true)
```

which should then only do an exact match on label contents of the field.